# Istio pilot version mismatch. How to upgrade it?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have upgraded istio from 1.6.0 to 1.6.8. Everything went without problems.
Verification with `kubectl get pods -n default -l istio.io/rev={revision}` returns that all pods are running by using 1.6.8, but `istioctl version` returns

```
client version: 1.6.8
istiod version: 1.6.8
pilot version: 1.6.0
data plane version: 1.6.8 (12 proxies)
```

Which indicates that pilot is still running on old version. I'm not able to find any information how to upgrade it without reinstalling whole istio.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The official docs contain a complete guide: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/upgrade/

Comment: I was following 1.6 upgrade docs: https://istio.io/v1.6/docs/setup/upgrade/
Control plane upgrade: `istioctl install --set revision=1-6-8`
Data plane upgrade: `kubectl label namespace staging istio-injection- istio.io/rev=1-6-8`
Verification steps. Nothing was mentioned there about deletion of old resources or pilot upgrades.
Document you have shared is for 1.7 client. Will look into it.

Comment: 1.Did you ugrade from older release to 1.6 and now to 1.6.8 or 1.6 was the first installed version? 2.Was there a pilot when you check that before upgrading to 1.6.8?  As far as I know [pilot is a part of istiod](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/upgrade-notes/#pilot) so it shouldn't be here.

Comment: Previously, several months ago, there was upgrade from 1.5.x to 1.6.0. Right now it was upgrade from 1.6.0 to 1.6.8. There was a pilot i believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is clean 1.6.0 install

```
istioctl version
client version: 1.6.8
control plane version: 1.6.0
data plane version: 1.6.0 (3 proxies)
```

There is 1.6.8 after canary install

```
istioctl version
client version: 1.6.8
pilot version: 1.6.0
istiod version: 1.6.8
data plane version: 1.6.8 (2 proxies), 1.6.0 (7 proxies)
```

Why does this happen? Because there are 2 versions working, original and canary.

As mentioned [here](https://dev.to/bufferings/istio-1-6-0-canary-upgrade-trial-326j)

> It was separated from control plane version into 2 parts: pilot version and istiod version.
>
> Btw, it is istio-ingressgateway which uses 1.6.0 in data plane version. It seems intended to update [ingress-gateway](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23923#issuecomment-630892188)

---

> I'm not able to find any information how to upgrade it without reinstalling whole istio.

If I understand correct you're not able to upgrade it with this version, the main issue here is that there is no option to delete old control plane, that's already covered in the 1.7 [version](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/upgrade/#canary-upgrades).

The same thing happened in this [tutorial](https://dev.to/bufferings/istio-1-6-0-canary-upgrade-trial-326j)

---

**Workaround** for this would be to install version higher than 1.7, then if you check documentation there are steps to [Uninstall old control plane](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/upgrade/#uninstall-old-control-plane) and [Uninstall canary control plane](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/upgrade/#uninstall-canary-control-plane).

---

Additional resources:

- https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/18900
- https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23889
- https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23923